# Can the Postgres data type NUMERIC store signed values?

Tags: postgresql, types, numeric, postgresql-9.1, signed

In PostgreSQL, I would like to store signed values `-999.9` - `9999.9`.
Can I use `numeric(5.1)` for this?

Or what type should I use?

Comment: The precision of a postgresql numeric is the total number of significant digits, and the scale is the number of decimal places required. 9999.9 has 5 digits and 1 decimal place, so yes, `numeric(5.1)` will be OK. See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) for details.

Comment: is numeric(5.1) OK for -999.9?

Comment: Why don't you try and insert a negative value and see what happens? Anyway, `numeric` is part of the sql standard, and yes, it's signed.

Answer (score 18):

You can certainly use the [arbitrary precision type `numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) with a precision of 5 and a scale of 1, [just like @Simon commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381974/can-the-postgres-data-type-numeric-store-signed-values/35375346#comment46943351_29381974), but with comma(`,`) instead of a dot (`.`) in the type modifier:

```sql
SELECT numeric(5,1) '-999.9' AS nr_lower
     , numeric(5,1) '9999.9' AS nr_upper;

 nr_lower | nr_upper
----------+----------
   -999.9 |   9999.9
```

The minus sign and the dot in the string literal do not count against the allowed maximum of significant digits (`precision`).
If you don't need to restrict the length, just use `numeric`.
If you need to enforce minimum and maximum, add a [check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

```
CHECK (nr_column BETWEEN -999.9 AND 9999.9)
```

`numeric` stores your number *exactly*. If you don't need the absolute precision and tiny rounding errors are no problem, you might also use one of the floating point types `double precision` (`float8`) or `real` (`float4`).

Or, since you only allow a single fractional decimal digit, you can multiply by 10 and use `integer`, which would be the most efficient storage: 4 bytes, no rounding errors and fastest processing. Just use and document the number properly.

[Details for numeric types in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: Thanks @Erwin, great answer!