# Can data type "Numeric" support negative numbers in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, precision, sqldatatypes

I have a column of numbers ranging from `-100` to `+100`. They have from 0 to 9 values after the decimal points. Here are some examples: `-32.1235, -5.1234, -12, 6, 6.3, 9.0`.

I'm trying to put them into a table and I'm receiving error -

> invalid input syntax for type numeric: "-"

I've tried changing the data type to `decimal`, but I find that it keeps reverting to `numeric`. And, I want these numbers to be stored precisely.

How do I input negatives for numerics?

Edit: There's another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381974/can-the-postgres-data-type-numeric-store-signed-values) that suggests just using data type numeric. I have cast my data as numerics and I'm still receiving the invalid input syntax message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that you are using a character that looks like a negative sign, but is not.  `numeric` and `decimal` are the same data type, by the way.  As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) explains:

> The types decimal and numeric are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard.

The following works fine for me:

```
select x, cast(x as decimal(10, 2)), cast(x as numeric(10, 2))
from (values (-32.1235), (-5.1234), (-12), (6), (6.3), (9.0) ) v(x);
```

And, as expected, the results are the same.  [Here](http://rextester.com/QOAZ39716) is a rextester.

Comment: How do I get a character that is the real negative sign?

Comment: @Sebastian . . . On my keyword, the hyphen next to the `0` works fine.  If that doesn't work, then you can try copying the character from the above code.

Comment: I think I know why it's not working. The negatives got formatted as (1,232.12) and I have this function in my query:                                     replace(replace(trim(replace("ColumnA", ',', '')),'(','-'),')','') AS "ColumnAFormatted",

Comment: Is there a better way of reformatting those numbers? They are stored as strings in the table I'm pulling from.